# How to calculate date and time difference?

Tags: php

Can somebody tell if my below code is correct.I calculate difference between date requested and current time.But I'm getting the `$timediff` value in negative like this: -28200

```
    $dateRequest =  "2015-08-21 15:16:02";
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
    echo "now ".$now=date('Y-m-d, g:i A',time());
    $timezone_offset = +8;
    echo "then ".$then=date('Y-m-d, g:i A', strtotime($dateRequest)+$timezone_offset*60*60);

    echo "<<".$timediff = strtotime($now) - strtotime($then);// in seconds
     if($timediff > 120)// 120  is 2 mins
    {
        echo "Expired Link";
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @Qirel, I think it's not...coz mine has time in hour min and sec also. SO the difference need to be done for date and time and not date alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

`$then` date is always in the future by 8 hours (8*60*60) = 28800

It's just basic maths

```
$now - ($then + 28800) = -28800
```